# Should you use quotation marks when transcribing an interview in which the speakers are identified before each quote?

Tags: quotations, quotation-marks, colons, dialogue

I apologize if the title is unclear, as I couldn't find a great way to phrase this.

What I'm asking is, which of the following would be correct?

Interviewer: Good morning, thank you for joining me.

John Doe: It's my pleasure.

or

Interviewer: "Good morning, thank you for joining me."

John Doe: "It's my pleasure."

Are the quotations marks necessary, should they be left out because the [Name] followed by [:] intro supersedes them, or is including them optional? Is there a specific rule that speaks to this? I've seen both formats used.

Thanks

Comment: If you're already using colons to signal speech, there is no need to also use the quotation marks that are normally used along with speech tags. That colons do the same job of signalling. The only *rule* is to do something that is immediately obvious. (Of course, you can use both, but you don't have to.)

Comment: How could it be that you're making this up from scratch? Are there really no precedents in your general field or particular organisation?

Either way, could you treat it as a play-script, only without the fiction?